# calculated item for Other

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

A field I use for columns in a pivot table has a large number of items.  Only a handful of these items are significant.  The rest I group into Others.  This I know how to do.  The issue I'm trying to solve is that every few weeks a new item is added to the data.  So when this happens I have to redefine the formula (Others := item1+item2+item3+item3+...+itemN).  Hoever, the set of significant items never changes.

Is there a way I can calculate Others as `<FIELD_TOTAL> - (itemA + itemB + itemC+itemD)`?

Comment: So basically, you want to calculate the sum of a set of data that gets a new element every few weeks, witout having to write the formula?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your data with this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,{"itemA","itemB","itemC","itemD"},0)),"other",B1)
```

If B1 is in the list between the curly braces, it returns the value in B1, otherwise it returns "other".

Comment: I want to do this using the calculated item feature if possible.